# 1-D raw, sample of a .wav file

Tags: java, android, vector, wav

I want to get a 1-D vector/list of double sample from a .wav file in an android application/environment.
Coud you help me to do it ?

Thanks in advance.
Kind regards.

Comment: Best to research a problem before asking a question, and then show the results of your research in your question, using it to help make the question more specific, higher quality and site appropriate. Please look at [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/)

Comment: Other similar questions: [java wav file data site:stackoverflow.com](https://www.google.com/search?q=java+wav+file+data+site:stackoverflow.com)